# How to append a row with user entered text value dynamically added rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one input field and one bootstrap modal box, i want to apend value to dynamically added rows continuesly,

Example if i click add row and click input field open popup and enter some values like "Joe" whenever i click add row that value (Joe) apend every rows.

and if i want to edit one row that row data only want to change, example now i just add one row and enter some text like (some text here), and i add 4 rows, the same text (some text here) will apended to 4 rows, then if i edit 3rd row input text, i just want to change that 3rd row text only. not for all rows..

I HOPE MY QUESTION IS UNDERSTAND.

Example here..

[image: reference image]

Example Fiddle here..

**[Fiddle Here..](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/8wt61Lsq/)**

Example Code here..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ok_button").on("click", function() {
    $("#acc_narrat0").val($("#cash_text:first").val());
  });
  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var idVal = $('#tab_logic tr:last').find('td:first').html();
    var matches = idVal.match(/\d+/g);
    if (matches != null) {
      counter = Number(matches) + counter + 1;
    }
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input value="' + $("#cash_text:first").val() + '" type="text" class="form-control required price" name="narr" placeholder="Enter your text here" id="acc_narrat' + counter + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" onchange="unname(this.id, this.value)"/></td>'

    cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);


    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
    bindScript();
    counter++;

  });
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    if ($("#tab_logic tbody tr").length == 1)
      $("#cash_text:first").val('');
    evaluateTotal();

  });
});

/* Apend value to all row */
$("#ok_button").on('click', function() {
  let val = $("#cash_text").val();
  $("#pay_narrat, #acc_narrat").val(val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic" style="width:60% !important">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
      <th class="text-center">
        Description*
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fst_row">
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- narrtion modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="myModalLabel">Description</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="cash_text" class="cash_text" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter your text here.."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button id="ok_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ok_button").on("click", function() {
  
    $(".act").val($("#cash_text:first").val());
  });
  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
 
    var counter = 0;
    var idVal = $('#tab_logic tr:last').find('td:first').html();
    var matches = idVal.match(/\d+/g);
    if (matches != null) {
      counter = Number(matches) + counter + 1;
    }
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    if($('.price').length > 0){
     var first_ele = document.querySelector('.price').value;
    }else{
     var first_ele ='';
    }
  
    cols += '<td><input value="' + first_ele + '" type="text" class="form-control required price" name="narr" placeholder="Enter your text here" id="acc_narrat' + counter + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" onchange="unname(this.id, this.value)"/></td>'

    cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);


    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    //setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
   // bindScript();
    counter++;

  });
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    if ($("#tab_logic tbody tr").length == 1)
      $("#cash_text:first").val('');
    evaluateTotal();

  });
});

/* Apend value to all row */
$("#ok_button").on('click', function() {
  //alert("in");
  let val = $(".act").val();
  $("#pay_narrat, #acc_narrat").val(val);
});
$(document).on('click','.price',function(){
 $('.price').removeClass('act');
 $(this).addClass('act');
  $("#cash_text").val($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic" style="width:60% !important">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
      <th class="text-center">
        Description*
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fst_row">
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- narrtion modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="myModalLabel">Description</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="cash_text" class="cash_text" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter your text here.."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button id="ok_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is in this line: `$("#acc_narrat0").val($("#cash_text:first").val())` It always refer to the first element. To resolve this you can set a variable that refer to the input once it is focused.

Also, you can use `hide.bs.modal` event to clean modal textarea after it closes. And you can `shown.bs.modal` to focus textarea on display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let inputElment = null;
  $("table").on("focus", "input[type='text']", function() {
    inputElment = jQuery(this);
  });

  $('#narratModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#narratModal textarea').val("");
  });

  $('#narratModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#narratModal textarea').focus();
  });


  $("#ok_button").on("click", function() {
    inputElment.val($("#cash_text:first").val());
  });

  $("#add_Row").on("click", function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var idVal = $('#tab_logic tr:last').find('td:first').html();
    var matches = idVal.match(/\d+/g);
    if (matches != null) {
      counter = Number(matches) + counter + 1;
    }
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input value="' + $("#cash_text:first").val() + '" type="text" class="form-control required price" name="narr" placeholder="Enter your text here" id="acc_narrat' + counter + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#narratModal" onchange="unname(this.id, this.value)"/></td>'

    cols += '<td><button type="button" class="adRow ibtnDel" style="width:70%;">x</button></a></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);


    var defVal = $("select[name=acctname]").find(":selected").val();
    if (defVal) {
      $("select[name=accountName]").find(`option[value=${defVal}]`).hide();
    }
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    setValCashVal('accountName'.concat(counter));
    bindScript();
    counter++;

  });
  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(_event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    if ($("#tab_logic tbody tr").length == 1)
      $("#cash_text:first").val('');
    evaluateTotal();

  });
});

/* Apend value to all row */
$("#ok_button").on('click', function() {
  let val = $("#cash_text").val();
  $("#pay_narrat, #acc_narrat").val(val);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="button" class="add_Row adRow" id="add_Row" value="Add Row">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover order-list" id="tab_logic" style="width:60% !important">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
      <th class="text-center">
        Description*
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fst_row">
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- narrtion modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="narratModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close cash-dismiss" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal_head" id="myModalLabel">Description</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <textarea id="cash_text" class="cash_text" maxlength="200" placeholder="Enter your text here.."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer narr_footer">
        <button id="ok_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary cashmodal_btn" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i just enter text in 1st row, that 1st row text apend dynamically added rows, whenever i wish to edit any rows text that row text only want to changed.. please refer my example image..

Comment: It is working. when you try to edit any row it will edit the text in that row only. Is there something else you wanted to do?

Comment: @Kalimah - your right, but my question and requirement is i just click add row button one row will added and i enter some text and again click add row now the same text want to come.. whenever i click add row the old text only wants to come append.. and if i try to edit any row it will edit the text in that row only.